# Convert dataframe to tidy format in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidy

I have a data frame with a structure as follows

```
> ls.str(df)

attachments : 'data.frame': 1103947 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ media_keys:List of 1103947
 $ poll_ids  :List of 1103947
author_id :  chr [1:1103947] "21572351" "21572351" "21572351" "21572351" "21572351" "21572351" "21572351" "21572351" "21572351" "21572351" ...
conversation_id :  chr [1:1103947] "1006266341341519872" "1006265425791987715" "1006251577747869696" "1006246236171722753" "1006246168991600642" ...
created_at :  chr [1:1103947] "2018-06-11T20:06:05.000Z" "2018-06-11T20:02:27.000Z" "2018-06-11T19:07:26.000Z" "2018-06-11T18:46:12.000Z" ...
entities : 'data.frame':    1103947 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ mentions   :List of 1103947
 $ annotations:List of 1103947
 $ hashtags   :List of 1103947
 $ urls       :List of 1103947
 $ cashtags   :List of 1103947
geo : 'data.frame': 1103947 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ place_id   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ coordinates:'data.frame':    1103947 obs. of  2 variables:
id :  chr [1:1103947] "1006266341341519872" "1006265425791987715" "1006251577747869696" "1006246236171722753" "1006246168991600642" ...
in_reply_to_user_id :  chr [1:1103947] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

and I want to convert it to a tidy format. Is there a neat little function to do this, that I don't know of? Google hasn't been to much help. Thanks in advance!

By tidy format, I mean something like this:

```
#> # A tibble: 25 × 31
#>    tweet_id       user_username text  conversation_id author_id lang  created_at
#>    <chr>          <chr>         <chr> <chr>           <chr>     <chr> <chr>     
#>  1 1406007405180… Phardiga      "RT … 14060074051803… 58755490  de    2021-06-1…
#>  2 1405617386405… dorothee_goe… "RT … 14056173864058… 97759337… de    2021-06-1…
#>  3 1405616047990… dejools       "RT … 14056160479909… 13065071… de    2021-06-1…
#>  4 1405615055555… LenaOetzel    "RT … 14056150555557… 97897581… de    2021-06-1…
#>  5 1405613064968… jenniferhenk… "RT … 14056130649684… 114774406 de    2021-06-1…
#>  6 1405610724026… Tobias_Schul… "Ihr… 14056107240266… 47919307  de    2021-06-1…
#>  7 1405393033558… HTMIBerlin    "‍…  14053930335589… 94052353… und   2021-06-1…
#>  8 1404808751857… Tobias_Schul… ".@j… 14048087518576… 47919307  de    2021-06-1…
#>  9 1404440929881… ASattelmacher "Oka… 14044409298812… 11508518… de    2021-06-1…
#> 10 1404393457427… dr_john_aus_b "#Ic… 14043934574273… 30635588… und   2021-06-1…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyr`, we could wrap with `unpack` (to unpack the data.frame columns into regular columns) and then with `unnest` to convert the `list` columns to regular columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  unpack(where(is.data.frame)) %>%
  unnest(where(is.list))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  media_keys poll_ids author_id conversation_id mentions annotations
       <int>    <int>     <int>           <int>    <int>       <int>
1          1        4         1               1        1           4
2          2        5         2               2        2           5
3          3        6         3               3        3           6
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(attachments = structure(list(media_keys = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L), class = "AsIs"), poll_ids = structure(list(4L, 
    5L, 6L), class = "AsIs")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), author_id = 1:3, conversation_id = 1:3, entities = structure(list(
    mentions = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L), class = "AsIs"), 
annotations = structure(list(
        4L, 5L, 6L), class = "AsIs")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks! When I run the code, I get the following error prompt: ```Error: In row 5, can't recycle input of size 2 to size 0.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.```

Comment: ```> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
In row 5, can't recycle input of size 2 to size 0.
Backtrace:
 1. tweets_115_congress %>% unpack(where(is.data.frame)) %>% unnest(where(is.list))
 3. tidyr:::unnest.data.frame(., where(is.list))
 4. tidyr::unchop(data, any_of(cols), keep_empty = keep_empty, ptype = ptype)
 5. tidyr:::df_unchop(cols, ptype = ptype, keep_empty = keep_empty)
 6. purrr::reduce(x_sizes, unchop_sizes2)
 7. purrr:::reduce_impl(.x, .f, ..., .init = .init, .dir = .dir)
 8. tidyr:::fn(out, elt, ...)```

Comment: @Quantizer note that I assumed that all your list elements have the same length as your original data column (based on your str).  Another assumption is that none of the list elements have any NULL values

Comment: @Quantizer i tried with NULLvalues, but it still does the conversion in `unnest` to `NA` i.e. `df$attachments$media_keys <- list(1, NULL, 3)`

Comment: As the error occurs in row 5, it would be a good option to dput few rows of your dataset to debug the issue. i.e. `dput(head(df), 10)`